# Averages of List in R script

Tags: r, rscript

I'm new to R and I'm trying to get student scores from a JSON file and do histograms and calculate average score but I'm not sure if there is an easier way to get all scores from the JSON string to do the average. Below is my code:

```
library("RJSONIO")

students='[{"SSN":"1234","score":99},{"SSN":"1235","score":100},{"SSN":"1236","score":84}]';
students <- fromJSON(students);

scores = list();
i = 1;

for (rec in students){
  scores[i]=rec$score;
  i=i+1;
}
```

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lapply` function to extract the `score` value from each list element, and then use `unlist` to convert the result to a vector:

```
scores <- unlist(lapply(students, function(x) x$score))
scores
# [1]  99 100  84
```

Now, you can just use `mean(scores)` to get the average.